# Ruby + Tk's canvas and shapes are bugging out

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I'm running Windows + Ruby2.3 and was messing with the `tk` library. I'm trying to get it to draw a grid of rectangles of different colors, but whenever I try to add a shape to the canvas my script crashes. Here's a stripped down version of the code:

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'
root = TkRoot.new
content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root)
canvas = TkCanvas.new(content)
line = TkcLine.new( canvas, 0, 0, 10, 10, :fill => 'red' )
Tk.mainloop
```

However, when I run it I get the following error + backtrace:

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/itemconfig.rb:115:in `hash_kv': wrong argument type nil (expected Array) (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/itemconfig.rb:115:in `itemconfig_hash_kv'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/canvas.rb:722:in `_parse_create_args'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/canvas.rb:735:in `create'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/canvas.rb:758:in `create_self'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tk/canvas.rb:751:in `initialize'
        from C:/nopathforyou.rb:9:in `new'
        from C:/nopathforyou.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know what to do about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've experienced the same bug, and I finally solve this issue by adding the code below:

```
module TkItemConfigOptkeys
    def itemconfig_hash_kv(id, keys, enc_mode = [], conf = [])
        hash_kv(__conv_item_keyonly_opts(id, keys), enc_mode, conf)
    end
end
```

It should be after the 'require' statements, say, your code should be like:

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'
module TkItemConfigOptkeys
  def itemconfig_hash_kv(id, keys, enc_mode = [], conf = [])
    hash_kv(__conv_item_keyonly_opts(id, keys), enc_mode, conf)
  end
end
root = TkRoot.new
content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root)
canvas = TkCanvas.new(content)
line = TkcLine.new( canvas, 0, 0, 10, 10, :fill => 'red' )
Tk.mainloop
```

After adding that, my code works like a charm.

Comment: @Punknoodles That would be greate.

Comment: @Punknoodles I've sent a pull request to Ruby/Tk and the contributors told me this bug has already been fixed but the fix happen after the Ruby release. Maybe you won't need that anymore in the future version.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby/Tk has fixed this bug in [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0318d35710c6a10fc86a291dbc8b0730b5292e0a).

So you can just update your tk library, as an alternative.